# Running VMware in Kali

Tags: vmware

How to run VMplayer in Kali Linux?

I installed VMplayer but after I select `Applications > System Tools > VMware Player` I'm getting this problem

[image]

I have already tried

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
apt-get install open-vm-toolbox
```

How to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Its kernel header problem that the kernel can't find the header of vmware log file and so he can't start the service.
You can watch [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF2qBiWqgvk) or read [this](http://www.drchaos.com/installing-vmware-tools-on-kali-linux/) blog.